# Deleted answer in between non-deleted ones

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

A [related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276977/what-do-you-think-about-shifting-all-deleted-answers-to-the-bottom-of-a-page-dis) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) seemed to no receive to much attention because the OP was sorting via Activity. According to the answer by @animuson♦ the votes tab shouldn't have this issue (emphasis mine):

> The **votes tab** is quite a bit different, though. It's the default tab that all users start on, and votes themselves indicate usefulness to the viewers. A deleted answer is not particularly useful to anyone as it is generally deleted because it was not useful or didn't answer the question, **which is why they get thrown down at the bottom** when you're viewing that tab.

However, on a recent question I answered (and then deleted when I saw someone had already answered the same thing as I was writing mine up on my mobile) I can see 3 zero voted answers including my deleted one.

The order of them is, although not consistent on every refresh:

- un-deleted
- deleted
- un-deleted.

(ignore my print screen/paint skills)

[image: part 1][image: part 2]

Can we have it implemented so the deleted answers are sorted after the none deleted ones?

Comment: Is it a bug? I don't know. Are you sorting by "votes", or not? Can't tell from the screenshots.

Comment: No self answer, and sorting by votes

Comment: @CodyGray I could add a link to the question so you could reproduce it but was trying to avoid any meta effect. And not sure if it's because it is my answer and so you viewing it with 10k privileges might affect it as well

Comment: @CodyGray Also there are 4 long answers above the zero score ones so print screening to show sorting by votes would be awkward

Comment: Post a link to the question please

Comment: [Question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570898/one-method-accepting-different-parameters/41571121)... avoid meta affect please, and note I wasn't able to reproduce it on every refresh of the page the order of the 3 zero scored answers seems to be random

Comment: Yours shows up at the bottom for me. This must have something to do with it being yours. I recall seeing similar behavior in the past with my own deleted posts.

Comment: @TinyGiant see the update to my comment but that could be the reason

Comment: If the content is deleted, it should be stuck to the bottom. I seem to recall something about that not being the case for your own deleted content. As such, it will get the same quazi-random sorting order as if it was not deleted.

Comment: [Apparently it's because we're pseudo-mods](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51730/153008), @tiny. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172853/consider-deletion-when-sorting-answers-by-votes, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260688/own-deleted-answer-sometimes-showing-above-non-deleted-answers-with-same-score, and others.

Comment: If you have less than 10,000 reputation, you only see your own deleted answers, and they are sorted in with the rest of the answers. Deleted answers are only pushed to the bottom of the page for users with 10,000 reputation who can see *all* deleted answers. I don't know the reasoning for it being done this way, but it's not a bug.

Comment: @animuson Thanks for chiming in, I've edited the question

Answer (score 1):

What's your setting for the sorting of answers? There are three choices:

[image]

Active - sorts the answers in order of most recently posted **or edited**.
Oldest - always sorts the answers with the oldest first.
Votes - sorts by score, but if posts are tied on the same score they are sorted randomly.

The default is "Votes", so it would be quite likely that between two visits where the scores haven't changed you'll see the answers in a different order.

Also, as [animuson states](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341316/deleted-answer-in-between-non-deleted-ones#comment431032_341316) your deleted answer is sorted normally with the non-deleted answers.