# Deleted answer appearing before non-accepted answer?

Tags: bug

I was looking at this question: [What are the new features in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38060436/what-are-the-new-features-in-c17)

Which contains lots of deleted answers. To my surprise, one of the deleted answers appears before the only non-deleted (but not accepted) answer on the page (screenshot at the end for <10k users).

I read somewhere that non-accepted answers are shown in a random order but I thought deleted answers were always shown after non-deleted ones.

Is this intended?

---

Screenshot for <10k users (comments at the top are comments on the question itself):

[image]

Comment: you sort by Active so you get answer with latest activity which happened to be deleted

Comment: The "Active" tab is the least useful way to sort posts by at least an order of magnitude.  But sure, it was the last one active so this is feature, not a bug.  Just make sure you didn't click it by accident.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes. But. [Please sort deleted answers to the bottom](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7505) is tagged status-completed so this looks like a bug.

Comment: @DavidPostill Maybe this just apply to sort by vote. I found a somehow duplicate that asks to push deleted answer to the bottom: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276977/what-do-you-think-about-shifting-all-deleted-answers-to-the-bottom-of-a-page-dis so I'll simply mark my question as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: @Hans I sometimes use it when a question with many views and many answers gets bumped to the homepage and I forgot to click the date link instead of the title. This leaves me scratching my head wondering why the sorting is so weird on each next question I open.